# Selecting a Tab in a Tabbed Panel works the first time I click the button

Tags: xpages

After I click the button it goes to the next tab, however, if I click the previous tab to edit something then click the button again, nothing happens.  Any idea why?  Here is the button code:

```
<xp:button value="Next" id="buttonNext1">
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
    submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panelMain">
    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
viewScope.currentTab = "tpCompanyInformation";
}]]></xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Answer (score 5):

I see you bound the SelectedTab or even the defaultTab value of to your `viewScope.currentTab` and set the viewScope variable in every button with your viewScope.currentTab = "id".

I would recomend setting the tab direct in the component by using `getComponent('tabbedPanel').setSelectedTab('tabid')`.

As a little goody: maby this Code helps you it will Create two buttons ('back' & 'next'), no mather how much tabs you will add to your panel the buttons should always work as forward and backward buttons.

ButtonBack:

```
    <xp:button id="button1" value="back">
                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="tabbedPanel1">
                            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var panel:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspTabbedPanel = getComponent('tabbedPanel1');
                var list:Array = panel.getChildren().toArray();
                var currentTab = panel.getSelectedTab();

                for(var i = 0; i < list.length;i++){
                    if(currentTab.equals(list[i].id)){
                        if(i > 0)
                            panel.setSelectedTab(list[i-1].id);
                        else
                            panel.setSelectedTab(list[list.length - 1].id);
                    }
                }

                    }]]></xp:this.action>
       </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Button Next:

```
<xp:button value="Next" id="buttonNext1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="tabbedPanel1">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript://
var panel:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspTabbedPanel = getComponent('tabbedPanel1');
var i:java.util.Iterator = panel.getChildren().iterator();

var currentTab = panel.getSelectedTab();

while(i.hasNext()){
    if(currentTab.equals(i.next().id)){
        if(i.hasNext())
            panel.setSelectedTab(i.next().id);
        else
            panel.setSelectedTab(panel.getChildren().iterator().next().id);
    }
}
    }]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```